# Security impact of MinSdkVersion on Android apps

Tags: android

I know that defining a low MinSdkVersion for Android apps impacts the security of an app. From what I know, basically all security improvements since that MinSdkVersion are not enforced for this app, as it supports Android versions where it is not available yet.

For example if an app uses the `MinSdkVersion 19` the mounted SD card is readable for the app.

Now to my question. Is there a list or collection of security implications for specific Android SDK versions?

For example, if the MinSdkVersion X is defined, the following security features are not guaranteed: `[...]`.

Or something similar to check the implications of the chosen MinSdkVersion.

Comment: This might be better suited for [Android.se].

Comment: @TomK. I've been considering that but thought due to the explicit security relation the question is better suited for the security SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know, basically all security improvements since that MinSdkVersion are not enforced for this app, as it supports Android versions where it is not available yet.

This is incorrect. `minSdkVersion` simply controls how old of an Android device your app can be installed upon.

> For example if an app uses the MinSdkVersion 19 the mounted SD card is readable for the app.

This is incorrect.

> Is there a list or collection of security implications for specific Android SDK versions?

No, sorry.